# On reducing screen size -The Side-navbar overlaps with main content and gives white space in the right side of the browser window screen

Tags: html, css

Hi i am working in web application . I have layout issues in it.
On Maximum browser screen .

Every thing works fine .

But when i reduce the screen size and try some navigation  and Horizontal scrolling i am getting two major layout issues .

Horizontal scrolling
1. The side nav bar overlaps with main content .
2. Getting white space in the right of the browser screen.

on clicking the nav menu, the main content jumps towards left side and overlaps with side menu

```
   <html>
    <body>
    <div id="app">
    <div class="main-content">
    <nav class="menu-fixed-top sticky-top"> </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="Page">
    <div class="Page-content">
    <nav  id="Page-nav"> 
    <ul class="nav nav-pills"></ul>
    <li  class="nav-item"> </li> </nav>
    <div class="Page-main">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </body>
 </html>

 <style>

html,
body,
#app,
.container-fluid {
      height: 97%;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      display: table;
}

.menu-fixed-top {
  background:$selected-color;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 11;
}
.Page {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.Page-content {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  position: relative;
}

.Page-main {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 16.6rem;
  height: 100%;
}

#Page-nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-top: 0px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  width: 15rem;
  min-width: 15rem;

  & ul {
    display: block;
  }
  & li {
    display: block;
  }
}

.nav-pills {
  .nav-link {
    color: #000000;
    border-radius: 9px;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
    font-size: 10pt;

    &.active {
      color: $selected-color;
      background: #ffffff;
      border: 1px solid #ffffff;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    &:not(.active) {
      border: 1px solid transparent;
    }

    &:hover {
      background: $navbar-default-bg;
      color: $highlight-dark-color;
    }
  }
}
 </style>
```

[image]

Comment: You are not using css syntax within the style tag. It looks like sass? Sass and less and their likes need compilation into css for the browser to read them. Rewrite in normal css syntax and it might work. Currently the browser is ignoring a lot of your styling.

Answer (score 0):

I think that U need to make adaptive page with:

Than in the file css make four block with code:

/*-992px-1200px*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px)

/*768px-992px*/
@media screen and (max-width: 992px)

/*-576px-768px*/
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)

/*-0px-576px*/
@media screen and (max-width: 576px)

And for this elemant you need a code Some width, Margin and do on

Comment: when ever i click the link in the side nav the main content is pushed towards left of the screen making the divs overlapping